# Excel - need to extract a machine ID that includes a number in a cell, regardless of its position in sentence

Tags: excel, excel-formula

It's my first time posting a question here :)

When exporting data from our enterprise ticketing system, we unfortunately do not have a specific column for a machine ID, but instead have "problem description" column which includes both the short description of the issue and the machine ID. The Machine ID always has numbers, but may contain only numbers or 2-4 letters before the number, with no spaces, examples are:

**XK2065**

**2092**

**BOZK10625**

The number of digits can vary, but is never more that six.

2 examples of the problem description:

1) **XK2065** - issue not detected, please investigate.

2) Please investigate why issue was not detected, machine ID is **XK2065**, ticket number 1425778.

So, the problem is that the unit ID can be located anywhere in the sentence and can also contain only numbers or 2 to 4 letters before the numbers.

Is there a function that can extract the machine ID, regardless of location, along with the beginning letters adjacent to the numbers if it has them? Additional condition I'd like is for a number of digits to be no more than 6, as sometimes ticket numbers may be included which are 7-digit.

A function would be preferable to VBA macro.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Simplest would be to develop a UDF in VBA using Regular Expressions. There are plenty of examples as to how to use Regular Expressions in VBA on this site.

Comment: Is your "machine ID" a serial number so many possible or a model number which will perforce be limited? Because you could do a find based on a list of model numbers...

Comment: Ron, this is exactly what I needed and I used what @JvdV had written, with adding a few more patterns. It works wonders!

SolarMike, the ID's are not linked to serial numbers, what makes it even worse is that not all machine ID's follow the same format, but this is where the solution given by Ron and JvdV comes in and does exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function should do what you need, using regular expression (like @RonRosenfeld suggested):

```
Function RegExID(str As String) As String

Dim rgx As Object
Set rgx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
Dim allMatches As Object
With rgx
    .Pattern = "\b[A-Z]{0,4}[\d]{4,6}\b"
    .Global = True
    .ignoreCase = True
    .MultiLine = True
End With

Set allMatches = rgx.Execute(str)

For Each Item In allMatches
    RegExID = Item.Value
Next

End Function
```

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly! I have found some additional patterns where, for example, some machine ID's have three letters, a number, then three letters. After having learned a bit about RegEx , I have added some other patterns I found and separated them by just putting | in between patterns.

Thank you so much! :)